# Express server : clone an existing document into a another collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I have an collection which is called "Tasks".

```
const TaskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 task_name:{
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 1,
    unique: true,
},
task_category: String,
task_xpreward: Number,
task_completed: Boolean,
task_difficulty: Number,  //1 = Easy, 2 = Medium, 3 = Hard, 4 = Very Hard, 5 
= Impossible
task_solution: String,
task_city : String
});
```

This acts like a pool of tasks where the user can choose from. When a user click on a certain task (to claim it).

It should be cloned into a another collection called "Taskuser". This collection act like a pool of tasks assigned to a certain userId.

```
const TaskuserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
task_name:{
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 1,
    unique: true,
},
userId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
  },
task_category: {
    type : String,
    required : true,
},
task_xpreward: {
    type : Number,
    required : true,
},
task_completed: {
    type : Boolean,
    required : true,
},
task_difficulty: {
    type : Number,
    required : true,
},                     //1 = Easy, 2 = Medium, 3 = Hard, 4 = Very Hard, 5 = Impossible
task_city : {
    type : String,
    required : true,
},
task_solution : String //Oplossing van de task, API gaat hierop checken
});
```

How can i make it so that when there is `PUT/POST` call to assign a task to his pool. That certain task will be cloned in the collection "Taskuser" with the UserId from the user that clicked on it ? I just need to know how i can clone a document from 1 collection and put it into a another collection.

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to referencing a userId to a task, you can easily do moving userId property to TaskSchema:

```
...,
userId: {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: User (if your user schema is called User)
         }
```

Doing in this way, when you make a PUT or POST, you can create a Task (POST) and then you can update when a task is assigned to user (PUT, with query like {$set: {userId :USER_ID}}).

If a task can be assigned to multiple user, your property can become an array, but if this array can grow up a lot, will be a little problem when you have to load it (GET) and then paginate (with aggregation framework) the users to not overload the request.
To avoid this, you can create different collections :

- Task collection,
- User collection,
- UserTask collection: (with userId property and Tasks list property) each time a user is created, a UserTask is created too and when a task is assigned to user, the id of task will be added to Task_Id property. Like this you can easily query task by userId or users by taskId.